# How are the images of both eyes combined to form one image?

Tags: human-biology, vision, human-eye, visual-system

When you see an object by one eye, ex.right eye, you see it from the right direction and the opposite if you see it by your left eye, but when you open both eyes, the image appears somehow centric in between.

> How does the brain combine both images to form the final image?

Comment: You might also ask "how does the image on the retina become inverted ?"

Comment: @blacksmith37 - that is a very different question, and for that matter a question based on an invalid premise, assuming the image gets flipped back again in the brain; it is not, as there is no retinotopic ground truth necessary in the brain. The merging of two retinal projections, however, is the very basis of the most important cue for depth vision, i,e., retinal disparity.

Comment: well to start the brain does not form an image, there is no homunculus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The visual system contain several stages in which the information from both eyes is progressively mixed and analyzed, starting in the lateral geniculate nucleus.

Even if you feel seeing just one merged object with both eyes, your brain is using both images to calculate the 3D position of that object.

One fun fact: The image that you feel centric, it is actually bias towards one of your eyes, the called "dominant eye". You can check what is yours by a [simple experiment](https://www.allaboutvision.com/resources/dominant-eye-test.htm)